# Is essential spectrum not relevant to the topology on it

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider $F: \mathcal{D}(F)\subset X\rightarrow X$, we can define the essential spectrum as the set $\{\lambda\}$ s.t. the Fredholm index of $\lambda-F$ is not zero. Fredholm index can be written as
$ind\  \lambda-F= dim Ker(\lambda-F)-codim\  ran(\lambda-F)$ , where these two terms are both algebraic concept, does that mean essential spectrum is not related to the topology on the space?

Comment: Perhaps there is an issue about whether the range of $\lambda-F$ is closed...?

Comment: @paulgarrett when codim is finite, the range will naturally be closed in any norm

Comment: I feel uneasy about a claim (maybe needlessly strong, so un-necessary) that finite-codimension subspaces are always closed. Yes, finite-dimensional TVS's (with the Hausdorff condition, note) have just one topology. But using AxCh we can make codimension-one algebraic subspaces that are not closed... But maybe this is needless worry...?

Comment: @paulgarrett https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_operator, please check the third line in the first paragraph

Comment: @paulgarrett that's what I am confused, because by such sorting, specturm is a concept purely algebraic

Comment: Ah! Ok, so this fact is not (as I mis-imagined) seemingly depending on a more general, but false, assertion. Thanks for the info! And, then, granting that result on Banach spaces, then, yes, the definition of Fredholm ops on Banach spaces does not directly refer to the topology... But the proof that it doesn't does use the topology? I guess we could define "Fredholm operators" on arbitrary TVS's an an axiomatic way by "requiring" what we can "prove" for Banach spaces...? Strikes me as all-too-easily begging the question... but maybe you have something subtler in mind...

Comment: @paulgarrett that's what I am confused.We can treat resolvent set a subset of Fredholm index zero. So but this classification, spectrum is an algebraic concept.Is that right?

Comment: @paulgarrett but of course u are right, we need Banach space for topological need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least as a place-holder answer, in light of some comments: the usual definition/basic properties (whether something is part of the definition, or a basic property, depends on one's choice of logical order, and there is not a unique such...) of Fredholm operators on Banach spaces certainly does use the fact that the ambient space is a Banach space. This does imply that certain properties are equivalent to others, etc.

(*Some* properties of compact and/or Fredholm operators still make useful sense on "nuclear spaces", but things do start to unravel... I myself do know a little about this sort of extension, but mostly enough to know that spectral theory mostly doesn't work well... I remember Prof. Charles McCarthy, who got his PhD at Yale in the hey-day of operator theory there, once telling me that people spent a lot of time and effort trying to make spectral theory work more generally, but that it mostly just did not.)

It is certainly possible to choose some defining collection (not uniquely determined!) for Fredholm operators on Banach spaces, and use the same terminology in an arbitrary TVS or algebraic vector space.

Since the most-useful aspects of Fredholm and/or compact operators are (so far as I know) correct and easily provable on Banach spaces, and mostly fail otherwise, I myself am not aware of a *useful* definition beyond that case.

Comment: for general operator, I am always expecting some purely algebraic decomposition like cylic decomposition for self-adjoint operator, but it seems what we can have is like Dunford integral which is quite rough

Comment: There are indeed various notions of vector/operator-valued integrals (my own favorite in terms of logical order is Gelfand-Pettis' "weak"... as in my course notes and book...), whose sense only depends on completeness or quasi-completeness of the TVS (or of the space of operators on it, which would include the non-normable "strong" topology on operators on a Banach space, in addition to the usual operator-norm top on operators on a Banach space...) But although various assertions would make sense, they still tend to fail, in greater generality...